# How do I run terminal commands in a script?

Tags: python, linux, terminal, raspberry-pi

I am currently running an Raspberry Pi 4b with an [x728 UPS](https://wiki.geekworm.com/X728#User_manual). I am trying to make a script so that when power gets cut off from the UPS, it would run a shut down script.

Currently, I have this -

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import subprocess

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(6, GPIO.IN)

while:
      if GPIO.input(6) == 1:
          subprocess.call(['shutdown', '-h', 'now'], shell=False)
```

This works in shutting down the Pi when power gets cut off, however, the UPS doesnt turn off, and in turn, I cant use the device's auto-turn on feature when the power comes back on.

In their [wiki](https://wiki.geekworm.com/X728-Software), they have a command `x728off` that you can run in the terminal to shutdown both the Pi and the UPS. It works great if I just typed it directly into terminal, however, I dunno how to put it in my code.

Comment: `how to put it in my code.` weell, `subprocess.call(['x728off'], shell=False)`??

Comment: @KamilCuk I tried, but it is just throwing an error "OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory"

Comment: Can you type `type x728off` in the terminal ?

Comment: @Philippe Thats it! it returned x728off is aliased to 'sudo x728softsd.sh'. Thank you so much...

Answer (score 0):

To run the command as it is use.

```py
import os
os.system("x728off")
```

or if you want to use subprocess module, use

```py
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["x728off"], shell=False)
```

Comment: Both didnt work. For os.system, it says "sh: 1: x728off: not found" and for the subprocess it says "OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory"